# determining metric with largest excursion

Tags: hypothesis-testing, poisson-binomial-distribution

I'm trying to use an algorithm to determine which of many metrics is the one with the largest excursion value from a baseline dataset.

For simplicity, let's say I have two measurements.
MetricA has a historical value of 20%, 1 std deviation= 5%.
MetricB has a historical value of 0.2%, 1 std deviation=0.2%

Both measurements are based on a batch size of 500 data points.

Let's say I measure a new data point that measures 30% on Metric A, and 1% on Metric B.  On an absolute basis, Metric A shows a larger deviation from the baseline value, but on a relative basis, Metric B shows a larger deviation.  What method can be used to determine which metric is showing the largest actual excursion from its baseline and/or what corrections would have to be made to make them comparable?